# Good logging approach in Flutter

Tags: logging, flutter, dart

What is a good logging approach in flutter.

Options

1. print() //bad
2. log() method
3. https://pub.dev/packages/logger

I am looking for something as easy as it is in native android. Eg, Log.d()which works in all cases like having to be called from widget or not.

Comment: Define "logging". I mean, `print()` is perfectly fine if by "logging" all you want is to log something to the console.

Comment: By logging i mean typical logging like how we do in java. In java we use logger rather than doing sysout.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question. What aspect of "logging" are you actually interested in? Printing to the console? Printing _prettily_ to the console? Filtering the output logs based on logging level? Saving the output logs to another destination (e.g. a file or an online repository)? Or are you merely looking for a logging option that allows you to "log" using the same syntax? (i.e. `Log.d`, `Log.e`, etc.)

Comment: If all you're concerned about is using something like the "logger" library in Java, the logger package you linked is based on it and is designed to be as similar as possible. And with a few tweaks, you could get something close to a global logging syntax as well.

Answer (score 1):

`print()` is not "bad" as you say.

However with `logger` package you can display several types of logs like warnings, infos, debug logs... Which is visually better than `print`.

Comment: Still waiting on OP to clarify what they mean by "logging", as it can mean more than just printing something to the console.

Comment: clarified in my comment above

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the third option, so that you can use different levels for your logs :

```
logger.v("Verbose log");
logger.d("Debug log");
logger.i("Info log");
logger.w("Warning log");
logger.e("Error log");
logger.wtf("What a terrible failure log");
```